# OpenAL Loading Two sounds Freezes Java

Tags: java, lwjgl, audio, openal

So I am currently using OpenAL to load sounds, however when I load more than a single sound with my library it's freezing everything. Here is the code currently associated to loading the sound.

```
public static int loadALBuffer(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int result;
        IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);

        // Load wav data into a buffers.
        AL10.alGenBuffers(buffer);

        if ((result = AL10.alGetError()) != AL10.AL_NO_ERROR) {
            throw new OpenALException(getALErrorString(result));
        }

        WaveData waveFile = WaveData.create(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path)));
        if (waveFile != null) {
            AL10.alBufferData(buffer.get(0), waveFile.format, waveFile.data,
                    waveFile.samplerate);
            waveFile.dispose();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No such file: " + path);
        }

        // Do another error check and return.
        if ((result = AL10.alGetError()) != AL10.AL_NO_ERROR) {
            throw new OpenALException(getALErrorString(result));
        }

        return buffer.get(0);
    }


public static int getLoadedALBuffer(String path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int count = 0;
        for (Iterator<String> i = loadedFiles.iterator(); i.hasNext(); count++) {
            if (i.equals(path)) {
                return buffers.get(count).intValue();
            }
        }

        int buffer = loadALBuffer(path);

        buffers.add(new Integer(buffer));
        loadedFiles.add(path);

        return buffer;
    }


public static int loadALSample(String path, boolean loop) throws FileNotFoundException {
        IntBuffer source = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        int buffer;
        int result;


        buffer = getLoadedALBuffer(path);
        AL10.alGenSources(source);

        if ((result = AL10.alGetError()) != AL10.AL_NO_ERROR)
            throw new OpenALException(getALErrorString(result));

        AL10.alSourcei(source.get(0), AL10.AL_BUFFER, buffer);
        AL10.alSourcef(source.get(0), AL10.AL_PITCH, 1.0f);
        AL10.alSourcef(source.get(0), AL10.AL_GAIN, 1.0f);
        AL10.alSource(source.get(0), AL10.AL_POSITION, sourcePos);
        AL10.alSource(source.get(0), AL10.AL_VELOCITY, sourceVel);
        AL10.alSourcei(source.get(0), AL10.AL_LOOPING, (loop ? AL10.AL_TRUE: AL10.AL_FALSE));

        sources.add(new Integer(source.get(0)));

        return source.get(0);
    }
```

And the main class code:

```
static int testSound;
static int testSoun;


//to add a sound call manager.loadALSample("path",is this looping) and add the variable. 
    public static void loadALData(SoundManager manager) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //test = manager.loadALSample("test.wav", false);
        testSound = SoundManager.loadALSample("res/sounds/test1.wav", false);
        testSoun= SoundManager.loadALSample("res/sounds/test2.wav", false);
        SoundManager.killALLoadedData();
    }
```

Let me know if you need any more information. This is hard to debug, I've got error checking and the first sound loads okay and then when the second sound goes to load it just freezes.

Answer (score 0):

This was occurring because I wasn't clearing out the loaded files after loading each sample, this was causing Java to lock up when trying to load into data.